# Maven no longer running tests

Tags: java, maven, testing, build

I was using `mvn test` to run my test suites, but after closing my terminal (actually my IntelliJ in which I was using the terminal) and reopening it, when running `mvn test` I simply get the following output:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.myPackage:myApp >-----------------------
[INFO] Building myApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.213 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-18T00:09:40+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That is, it never even finds any tests anymore, let alone runs them.
Why is this happening? What could have changed from reopening my terminal session to it not working anymore?

Worth noting that `mvn package` seems to have broken as well. I get a `Cannot find main class` error now when I try and run my jar, when I didn't before.

Comment: Maybe you’re in a different directory? It would be helpful if you can share your `pom.xml`. Ideally, share the entire project using GitHub or a similar site.

Answer (score 1):

`[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------`

This line should tell you the packaging type is pom. In general the only plugins bound to `pom` are the maven-install-plugin and maven-deploy-plugin, hence no tests are executed.
I assume this should be `jar`.